# Why do matlab and python give different answers for the same mathematical question?

Tags: python, matlab

in python I have the equation:

```py
coef = 3*dyalo /(dxalo*dxalo) - (2*ya1lo+ya1hi)/dxalo
```

where dyalo,dxalo,ya1lo,ya1hi are all variables

in matlab I have what should be the same equation written as

```matlab
coef = 3.d0*dyalo/(dxalo*dxalo) - (2.d0*ya1lo+ya1hi)/dxalo;
```

with the same variable names.
I have printed each variable before they are called but after being assigned value in both programs, and each variable has the same value in both programs.

my code is giving the python answer roughly a factor of 3 larger.

edit: the matlab code is the one giving the correct answers, just wondering why python doesn't match.

The variable values are dyalo: -7.2e-4 , dxalo: 0.0062, ya1lo: -.1165, ya1hi: -.1165
The matlab output is .002, python output is 5.99e-3

copied from matlab code:

```matlab
disp(dyalo); disp(dxalo); disp(ya1lo); disp(ya1hi);
coef(3,i)= (3.d0*dyalo/(dxalo*dxalo) - (2.d0*ya1lo+ya1hi)/dxalo);
disp(coef(3,1))
```

copied from matlab command window:

```
-7.2189e-04

    0.0062

   -0.1165

   -0.1165

    0.0020
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Give us all of the variables in python along with their values, what is the output in matlab, what about in Python?

Comment: @Kraigolas I have put in the variables. part of the problem is that the matlab code belongs to someone else, and if I copy and paste it into a new matlab page it gives a different answer, even though I know all of the variables and their values.

Comment: Using the values you give, I get `0.0056` in MATLAB, very close to what you get in Python. But it is very likely that you typed some numbers in wrong, or with different precision. Use `format long` and look at the values in the original MATLAB code again.

Comment: Note also that `0062` is a strange way to write a number, this might be a typo.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, I meant dxalo =  0.0062 thanks.

Comment: In that case, the output is `50.7518` in MATLAB, very far away from either of your two results. Please go double-check all your numbers!

Comment: -7.2189e-04

    0.0062

   -0.1165

   -0.1165

    0.0020 

these are the values when I display the variables and the answer in matlab

Comment: disp(dyalo); disp(dxalo); disp(ya1lo); disp(ya1hi);
coef(3,i)= (3.d0*dyalo/(dxalo*dxalo) - (2.d0*ya1lo+ya1hi)/dxalo);
disp(coef(3,1))

This is copy and pasted from the code, and what I put above is copy and pasted from command window

Comment: `3.d0` is not valid MATLAB, that should error.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: I had never seen that before either, but it does not error. It is the same as `3`. No idea why.

Comment: @st123: did you do `format long` like I suggested?

Comment: So `coef(3,i)` is the same as `coef(3,1)`? Why not simplify things, and post a [mre]?

Comment: @CrisLuengo interesting, I though `d0` was a variable here. Anyway, this can not really be helped without a [mcve] and op does not give one

Comment: @CrisLuengo This is Fortran syntax. A lot of numerical MATLAB code is "ported" (= copy-pasted) Fortran.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether this is the issue or not, but I see in your matlab code that you have a `.d0` in both terms in your equation.  I'm not personally familiar with this syntax, but could that be the reason why Matlab is giving you a different answer? Edit: This is not the issue.  Maybe python is running numerical approximation methods?

Comment: the .d0 requests a certain level of precision, it is carried over from a different language but doesn't do much in matlab I believe. The matlab answer is also the correct one.

Comment: Yes I think I remember learning that a while back.  Searching for symbolic syntax in code is always really tedious on any search engine it seems....

Comment: Have you considered that python is using less precise numerical approximations in binary for the numbers, and is therefore returning less accurate results.  Here's a good article about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Try inputting ```.1+.1+.1==.3``` into a python shell.  Mine returned ```False```

Comment: How would I avoid or fix that problem? it is causing pretty significant changes to my outputs

Comment: @Patrick: MATLAB does the computations in exactly the same way (double precision floating point). OP’s problem here, as I have alluded to in the comments under the question, is that the numerical values are rounded, MATLAB is using values with a lot higher precision than MATLAB in those computations.